# Trying to export function without success with JavaScript, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I'm trying to learn Node.js and I have a pretty good app now, but I wanted to implement a library (venom-bot) to send some text messages. My problem is that I'm having trouble trying to use functions outside the primary file. Here is my code:

```
// Dependencies
const server = require("./lib/server")
const venom = require("venom-bot")

// Declare the app
const app = {}

// Init function
app.init = () => {
    // Start the server
    server.init()
}

// Init venom-bot
venom.create().then((client) => start(client))

// A function to test if I can send the message
async function testing(msg) {
    await msg.sendText(...some code here...)
}

function start(client) {
    app.msg = client

    // Here, if I pass app.msg as an argument, works
    // My problem is that I can't use app.msg outside of here,
    // even with the module.exports down there
    // (I'm trying to use it on a helpers.js file).
    testing(app.msg)

    // Execute the application
    app.init()
}

// Export the app
module.exports = app
```

On the **helpers.js** file I'm requiring it this way:

```
// Dependencies
const app = require("./index.js")

// A function to test
async function sendMsg(msg) {
    await msg.sendText(...some code here...)
}

helpers.send = () => {
    sendMsg(app.msg)
}

module.exports = helpers
```

Whenever `helpers.send` gets invoked, it should correctly use the async function right above the `helpers.send` passing the `app.msg` as argument, at least I think it should. What I'm missing here?

The error I got is:

> (node:18148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendText' of undefined

On testing purpose, I'm trying to simple call that helper when I receive a get request to a specified route.

Comment: Can you display a code snippet where you are trying to use the `helpers.send` function?

Comment: Make sure when you call your `async` functions in a non-`async` function (e.g., calling `sendMsg` from `helpers.send`) you are using `.then()` on the promise

Comment: @ElijahEnuem-Udogu I was simple calling it from a get request to a route. When I call the route, node crash with this error: `(node:18148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendText' of undefined`

Comment: Please post the code that requires the *helpers.js*  module and calls the `send` method.

Comment: How do you make sure that the `app` is started (and has a `.msg` property) before calling `send`?

Comment: The code from where I call the helpers: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tfiorese/cnq5uz4s)

Comment: @Bergi Honestly I don't know. I bought a online course to learn pure NodeJS and it's a little old. Promises didn't existed yet, and this library that I'm trying to use is all about promises. I don't want to go deep right now on promises, I just wanted to use the one function that goes in there that send the messages, and that the function should be available when the user request to receive a message. (Like, check if the site X is up, and the answer should go trough this messaging service).

Comment: @Bergi the lib docs only tell to start it, and then to send the msg use "await client.sendText"... but this only works inside the start(client) function. Outside of it, client does not exists. Basically what I'm trying to do is access this client outside of the start(client) function, and outside the file it rests (as I said, I want to call it from the helpers.js). [here is the docs](https://orkestral.github.io/venom/). I tought that assigning app.msg = client inside the function, it should be available when the module.exports does it job

Comment: Yes. Uh, no, just don't do that. Put everything (that needs the client) inside that `start` function. Call the other code from there, and pass them the `client` they need to send messages.

Comment: "*I tought that assigning `app.msg = client` inside the function, it should be available when the module.exports does it job*" - no, `venom.create()` is asynchronous. It will add the property to the exported object, yes, but only later.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, it worked like a charm. Instead of starting the venom on the index, I moved it to the helpers.js, and then I placed all the helpers inside the `start` function. So I can call it everytime I need. Thank you very much!